# Python, toggle variables in a script

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've got a script running that I want to toggle between different variables.

Let's say I've got a list of urls and I want to concatenate one of the variables a, b or c. I don't care which but I'd expect the variables to repeat but the list would run through once.

`v` would end up looking like

- `url1+string1`
- `url2+string2`
- `url3+string3`
- `url4+string1`
- `url5+string2`
- `etc`

  ```
  def function1():

      list = [url1,url2,url3,url4,url5.......]

      a = 'string1'
      b = 'string2'
      c = 'string3'


      for i in list:
          v = i+(a then b then c then a then b then c)
  ```

I was able to get this to work on my own but I'm new and learning, does anyone have a more elegant solution to this?

```
a = 'a'
b = 'b'
c = 'c'

list1 = ['string1','string2','string3','string4','string5','string6','string7','string8']
list2 = [a, b, c]
c = 0
for i in list1:
    if c == len(list2):
        c = 0
    vv = i + list2[int(c)]
    c = c + 1
    print vv
```

it returns what I was looking for but it's messy:

- string1a
- string2b
- string3c
- string4a
- string5b
- string6c
- string7a
- string8b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can utilise [itertools.cycle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) to repeat one of the iterables, eg:

```
from itertools import cycle, izip

list1 = ['string1','string2','string3','string4','string5','string6','string7','string8']
list2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']

for fst, snd in izip(list1, cycle(list2)):
    print fst + snd # or whatever

#string1a
#string2b
#string3c
#string4a
#string5b
#string6c
#string7a
#string8b
```

Note that while `cycle` will repeat its elements indefinitely, `izip` stops on the shortest iterable (`list1`).

Answer (score 0):

```
list = [url1..1]
list2 = [a, b, c]
for i in list:
    for a in list2:
        v = i+a
```

EDIT

Okay, that makes more sense-

How about this...

```
set_it = iter(list2)
for i in list:
    try:
        a = set_it.next()
    except:
        set_it = iter(list2)
        a = set_it.next()
    v = i+a
```

Though I feel the same as you- there is probably a smoother way to accomplish that...

Comment: My apologies, I don't think I explained clearly. This will create 3 variables that start with URL1, URL2, etc. I only want the records from LIST to be pulled once and pull a random value from list2.